# Previously overstayed US, ESTA denied, is visa likely to be approved?

Tags: usa, esta, b1-b2-visas

My mother used to live and work in the US, as this was up until the mid 90s I was listed on her passport and visa. We left the US in 1994 (I was 5). My mum was unaware at the time that we actually overstayed, we believe by about 2 weeks.

I was delayed in immigration when I came back in 2009 and 2012 for this reason. I was allowed through, probably because of my age at the time. I have since applied for a redress number and managed to enter fine.

We now want to go on holiday with my mum back to America. Problem is we still don't have the exact information on what the overstay period was but clearly there was one due to my issues. I entered "yes" to the relevant question on the ESTA form and so it was of course declined.

The only option is now a visa at the embassy. Has anyone experienced anything similar? How generous are they with issuing visitor visas?

Comment: I don't know if I understand - the only overstay was when you were 5?

Comment: Personal opinion. 2 week overstay in 1994 (and you were underage): no problem. If she worked on a non-working visa: the can have more troubles, but not you.

Comment: Worth saying that the answers are going to be different for you and for your mum.